# What does colon (':') in bash variable resolution syntax mean?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to decode this assignment:

```
jvm_xmx=${jvm_xmx:-1024}
```

Comment: where is the semicolon (`;`)?

Comment: Yep, seems like a duplicate. But original topic title makes it unsearchable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

man page for bash:

```
${parameter:-word}
          Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
          word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

So if jvm_xmx is already set to something, it is left unchanged.
If it is not already set to something, it is set to 1024.

Example:

```
$ echo $jvm_xmx

$ jvm_xmx=${jvm_xmx:-1024}
$ echo $jvm_xmx
1024
$ jvm_xmx=2048
$ jvm_xmx=${jvm_xmx:-1024}
$ echo $jvm_xmx
2048
$
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. What does it mean when `parameter` is @ ? For example: `${@:10}`

Comment: Best to submit a whole new question for that, if the man page doesn't cover it for you.